# How to debug realm feature in Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have set the realm setting in server.xml host section to something like this:

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"  driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"  
         connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" connectionName="test" connectionPassword="test"  
             userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userRoleTable="user_roles" 
       roleNameCol="user_role" />
```

Also in web.xml:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>  
    <web-resource-collection>  
        <web-resource-name>critical</web-resource-name>  
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>  
        <http-method>GET</http-method>  
        <http-method>POST</http-method>  
    </web-resource-collection>  
    <auth-constraint>  
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>  
    </auth-constraint>  
</security-constraint>  

<login-config>  
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>  
    <form-login-config>  
        <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>  
        <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>  
    </form-login-config>  
</login-config>
```

And I have the databased set up. However when login.jsp is envoked, even I entered the right password I was redirected to error.jsp

I want to know if there is a way to find what's wrong during the process. Can I do it in Eclipse or any other hints that may solve the problem?

Comment: Do you see anything in the log files ? Also, did you create and populate the appropriate tables ?

Comment: I think I have the right tables. Where can I find realm logs?

Comment: Check the files in the logs folder of Tomcat.

Comment: @Santosh It says ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

Comment: The driver class files `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Drive` are packaged in a jar file. The possible jar which contain this are `mysql-connector-java.jar` or  `mm.mysql.jar` Check for any of these jars put them in `lib` folder in `tomcat`.

Answer (score 16):

To get the debug information from the Realm authentication steps, follow this procedure.

When you define your Realm in the server.xml, add debug="9" to the definition (you can of course use a lower number for less detail).

```
<Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"  driverName="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"  
   connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" connectionName="test" connectionPassword="test"  
   userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" userCredCol="user_pass" userRoleTable="user_roles" 
   roleNameCol="user_role" debug="9" />
```

You also need to add this to your logging.properties file:

```
org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.realm.useParentHandlers = true
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.useParentHandlers = true
```

You may also need to add this, to prevent bufferring of the logs.  If you do, remember to remove it after you've finished debugging.

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.bufferSize = -1
```

Now, the debug logs for the realms should end up in the catalina.out file.

Comment: No luck for Eclipse 2022-03 + Tomcat 8.5.79. Nothing extra is logged following the instructions above.

Answer (score 1):

For others finding this issue, I found the following worked for Tomcat 8.5.40:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm.useParentHandlers = true
```

The key fact appears to be that your logging travels through several layers of definitions and will be trimmed by the first one that has a lower level so you need to make sure that each bit it passes through is FINEST or ALL.

Hopefully this will save someone some time ;)

Ian.