# Tomcat DataSourceRealm not showing any logging

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, logging, jersey

I'm implementing a REST-API in Java, using Jersey3 and a Tomcat10. In order to provide/restrict access to some endpoints for specific roles, I would like to use a `DataSourceRealm`.

The configuration in my `context.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<Resource type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              name="jdbc/myDB"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl"
              username="xx"
              password="xx"/>

<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.DataSourceRealm" debug="99"
           dataSourceName="jdbc/myDB" localDataSource="true"
           userTable="USERS" userNameCol="USERNAME" userCredCol="PASSWORD"
           userRoleTable="USER_ROLES" roleNameCol="ROLENAME"/>
```

The `dataSource` is also defined in my context.xml and can be accessed with JNDI.

In my `web.xml` I defined the following security constraint:

```xml
<security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Some name</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/data</url-pattern>
            <http-method>GET</http-method>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

So every `GET` request with the pattern `/api/data` requires the role `Administrator`

Table `USER_ROLES` has one entry with `USERNAME=admin` and `ROLENAME=Administrator`.

Also, I've added these lines:

```xml
<login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>Administrator</role-name>
    </security-role>
```

For doing the obvious.

A corresponding endpoint is defined like this:

```java
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/data")
    @RolesAllowed({"Administrator"})
    public Response getData(...)
```

Added these lines to my log-config:

```
org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.realm.useParentHandlers = true
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.useParentHandlers = true
```

Calling http://localhost:8080/myapp/api/data in a GET with Authentication header `Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=` --> admin:admin

Restricting access so far works and my `DataSourceRealm` seems to be taken into account. Although there are no logs from the when someone is authenticating.

What would I need to add, in order so see logs from the DataSourceRealm?
Any help/input would be much appreciated.

Comment: Failed authentication is not logged, unless you increase the log level of `org.apache.catalina.realm` to `DEBUG`. Did you add your user credentials to the `USERS` table?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz yes, credentials are username admin and password admin.
With which param would I add the log level?

Comment: Add `org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL` to the `logging.properties` file and restart the server.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz many thanks! That brought some light into the dark. Unfortunately, the dataSourceName seems not to be found, although I've added a ResourceLink...

Comment: Yes, you have a typo `jdbc/mddDB` instead of `jdbc/myDB`. Also the `ResourceLink` is not required.

Comment: Can you add the exception text and stack trace, instead of paraphrasing it?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I updated the initial post. There is no stacktrace shown, all I get is a HTTP 401 from my tomcat. No stacktrace, no logs - nothing. Log levels are set like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311496/how-to-debug-realm-feature-in-tomcat/20648113 ... something seems totally off :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229169/discussion-between-piotr-p-karwasz-and-remo).